# How can I destroy a clone (in this case a laser shot by a spaceship) when it leaves a trigger2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's my current code;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameAreaCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D Ammo)
    {
        if (Ammo.CompareTag("Ammo"))
        {
            Destroy(Ammo);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to destroy the laser without destroying any other lasers.

Comment: Can you explain better your scene?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are destroying a component. If you want to destroy the gameobject that is holding that component try `Destroy(Ammo.gameobject)`;

Comment: No problem, if that helped please consider giving my answer a score and marking it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your code is set to destroy the Collider Component attached to the laser GameObject which has exited the trigger, not the GameObject itself.  Altering the code like this should destroy the entire laser object.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameAreaCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Ammo"))
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```